# Is it possible to edit the maven build process within a plugin to change the behavior of other plugins?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

New to Maven and I probably won't explain this correctly but here goes...

If I have the following project structure:

```
Project A ---> Library 1 ---> Library 2
```

Where `Project A` depends on `Library 1` (`Library 1` is a dependency in `Project A`'s pom) and `Library 1` depends on `Library 2`.

Is it possible in a maven plugin to change the build process so any plugins executed later in the process won't have access to the same structure?

As an example, lets say I want to remove `Library 1` as dependency of `Project A` and instead replace it with `Library 2`. So after my plugin runs, any future plugins see the project structure as:

```
Project A --> Library 2
```

If that is possible, can the solution be adapted to a structure where `Library 1` depended on `Library 2-10` and they all were included in the project structure while still removing `Library 1`?

My actual use case is I want a dependency to be included during compile time, but not during run time, and yet I want all of it's transitive dependencies to still be included. `<scope>provided</scope>` accomplishes the first part but also excludes transitive dependencies.

And before someone answers with "change your project structure" - it can't be done. Either I figure out a way to make this work nicely with maven, or I have to script the deletes of the deployable (this sucks).

Comment: Does having Project A's pom explicitly include Library 2-10 as dependencies not work for some reason?

Comment: @Sbodd It would work, but due to the way the projects are built and tested, that can't be done.